# Stuck With Weird Encoding in Javascript

Tags: javascript, character-encoding

I'm working with a third party API (i.e Read it Later API) and I notice that all the strings are being returned in the following format:

> http:&#92;/&#92;/www.fourhourworkweek.com&#92;/blog&#92;/2007&#92;/11&#92;/07&#92;/how-to-learn-b
>   Philip Greenspun's Weblog &#92;u00bb Stupid white man criticizes smart Chinese woman

Now, I know that '&#92;' is really a '\' and that "&#92;u00bb" really stands for \u00bb, which stands for '»'.

But how exactly would I decode that using Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This string has been JavaScript escaped and then HTML encoded.

So first you have to decode the HTML:

```
var foo = "http:&#92;/&#92;/www.fourhourworkweek.com&#92;/blog&#92;/2007&#92;/11&#92;/07&#92;/how-to-learn-b Philip Greenspun's Weblog &#92;u00bb Stupid white man criticizes smart Chinese woman";

var element = document.createElement('div');
element.innerHTML = foo;
foo = element.firstChild.data;
```

and then the JavaScript.

Unfortunately, I don't know a good way to do this, so I am resorting to `eval`. Please comment if you can spot a better way!

```
foo = eval("'" + foo.replace("'", "\\'").replace('\n', '\\n') + "'");
alert(foo);
```

Comment: This is the right approach for sure, but I'm still encountering some errors in the eval step. I think the newline character is breaking it. I'll go fix it and come back with a final solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you are using str.replace? Like this:

```
    var str="http:&#92;/&#92;/www.fourhourworkweek.com&#92;/blog&#92;/2007&#92;/11&#92;/07&#92;/how-to-learn-b Philip Greenspun's Weblog &#92;u00bb Stupid white man criticizes smart Chinese woman";
    str=str.replace (/&#92;/ig,"\\");
```

results on [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rame0/yHASJ/)

Comment: It's only working in this case, but it's not a general solution.

Answer (score -1):

The string looks escaped, try running your string through the `unescape(string)` function in javascript, that should give you back the original version.

Comment: The string has been escaped, twice using two different encoding schemes. `unescape` decodes from a third encoding scheme (so it won't help at all) and is deprecated anyway.